# Can I use L'Hopital's rule to prove this sequence converge, and is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> If $0 < s < 1$, then prove that $ns^{n-1}$ is bounded for all $n \geq 1$.

It is possible to view n as a variable so the criterion for L'Hopital's rule are satisfied and we get $n \rightarrow \infty$, $\frac{n}{s^{1-n}} \rightarrow 0$ so this proves that our sequence converges to 0 and thus is bounded bounded. Is this ok?

Comment: Yes, you can use L'Hopital's Rule.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use Hospital's rule. Another way to show that $\sup_{n\geq 1}n s^{n-1}$ is finite (without derivatives) is to remark that since $\frac{n}{n+1}\rightarrow_{n\rightarrow +\infty} 1$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{n}{n+1}>s$ for all $n\geq N$. This last inequality is equivalent to
$$ns^{n-1}> (n+1)s^{(n+1)-1}$$
for all $n\geq N$. Thus
$$0\leq ns^{n-1}\leq \max_{j=1}^N js^{j-1}$$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Option:

Set $s= \dfrac{1}{1+a}$, where $a >0;$

$f(n):=(1+a) \dfrac{n}{(1+a)^n};$

$(1+a)^n =$

$1+na+n(n-1)/2!+..>na;$

$f(n)<(1+a)\dfrac{1}{a}$, and we are done.